# How to display on top of Stackbar chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a stackBar Chart. I want to display one value on top of the bar chart and not for each stack of the bar. Iam using MpAndroichart library and by default it is displaying bar like in week1.

I want to display value on bar like for week1 and not as week2.

[image]

Comment: Where is your code? Post some screen shot

Comment: I have editted my post with usecase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also trying to figure this out today and I have done it with a little trick.Here's what I have done:

```
private BarData generateBarData()
{
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<mMonths.length; i++)
    {
        xVals.add(mMonths[i]);
    }

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals = new ArrayList<>();
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {15, 5, 5}, 0));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {12, 2, 6}, 1));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {15, 3, 4}, 2));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {15, 5, 1}, 3));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {13, 4, 1}, 4));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {10, 2, 1}, 5));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {15, 10, 2}, 6));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {15, 2, 1}, 7));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {14, 3, 6}, 8));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {15, 7, 2}, 9));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {15, 3, 1}, 10));
    yVals.add(new BarEntry(new float[] {11, 2, 4}, 11));

    ValueFormatter custom = new MyBarValueFormatter(mContext);

    BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(yVals, "Data Set");
    set.setBarSpacePercent(45f);
    set.setColors(getColors());

    set.setHighlightEnabled(false);
    set.setValueFormatter(custom);
    set.setDrawValues(true);

    BarData barData = new BarData(xVals, set);

    return barData;
}

private int[] getColors() {
    int[] colors = new int[3];
    colors[0] = getResources().getColor(R.color.barColor1);
    colors[1] = getResources().getColor(R.color.barColor2);
    colors[2] = getResources().getColor(R.color.barColor3);
    return colors;
}
```

In above code I have generated sample data for the BarChart and I have done my trick in **MyBarValueFormatter** class as below.

```
public class MyBarValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;
    private Context context;

    int toggle;
    float totalVal;

    public MyBarValueFormatter(Context context){
        toggle = 0;
        totalVal = 0;
        this.context = context;
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,##0");
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {

        if(toggle % 3 == 0){
            toggle++;
            totalVal =  value;
            return "";
        }
        else if(toggle % 3 == 1){
            toggle++;
            totalVal =  totalVal + value;
            return "";
        }
        else{
            toggle++;
            totalVal = totalVal + value;
            return context.getResources().getString(R.string.rupee) + " " + mFormat.format(totalVal) + "000";
        }
    }
}
```

This will not only show the top value in Stacked Bar Chart but will also show the sum of all the stacked values in the bar. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: @manindersingh  I don't see fun set.setBarSpacePercent(45f);. Can you help to set spacebar

Answer (score 0):

```
for (IDataSet set : mChart.getData().getDataSets()){
    set.setDrawValues(set.isDrawValuesEnabled());
}
```

Use this for display value on top of bar.

Comment: Actually the sum of all the values for all my bars in barchart is 100. Each stack would represent %value. But on top of my bar I want ti display a different value which I am fetching form another attribute. Say total price.